# Error 13 en visual basic con Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Me estoy volviendo un poco loco con esto... porque no le encuentro lógica alguna.

Partamos de la base que esto estaba funcionando hasta ayer, y llevo un montón de horas sin saber que le pasa ni encontrar una solución.

Tengo un formulario, en el que hay varios campos que proceden de una tabla o si se inserta un registro nuevo va a la tabla. Son empleados y se trata de que con cada alta, baja, modificación etc, se envíen una serie de correos preformados con los datos necesarios para cada caso.

El codigo es este

```
Private Sub MailSentAXX_Click()

'Es necesario añadir la referencia Microsoft Outlook Library (herramientas/referencias)
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With OutMail
.To = "correodeXX@loquesea.es"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "[XX] Nueva Incorporacion " & "Alta de" & " " & NOMBRE & " " & APELLIDOS & "(" & INCORPFECHA & ")"
.body = "Buenos días, " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "UN MONTON DE TEXTO Y VARIABLES "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Recibe un cordial saludo" 'The body of the mail
.Send 'tambien se puede usar .Display y lo muestra por si hay que añadir un adjunto o editar
End With
MsgBox "Se ha enviado el alta a XX de " & NOMBRE & " " & APELLIDOS, vbInformation, "PROCESS COMPLETE"

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Desde ayer me da un error 13 y que no coinciden los tipos en:

```
.Subject = "[XX] Nueva Incorporacion " & "Alta de" & " " & NOMBRE & " " & APELLIDOS & "(" & INCORPFECHA & ")"
```

siendo NOMBRE una cadena de texto corto, igual que APELLIDOS, e INCORPFECHA un cadena de fecha

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda, porque yo ya no sé ni para donde ir con esto.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado...
Pero con una solucion extraña.
Es un access con varias tablas y formularios que da servicio de comunicacion en la empresa para muchos cometidos.
Nada esta en editable por los usuarios, que son varios, y protegido.
Pues aqui viene lo raro. El formato de una fecha ha pasado a ser fecha/hora extendida.
En cuanto lo he cambiado todo funciona.
Pero estoy flipando con el cambio de formato... Porque esa tabla no la he abierto en modo diseño desde hace meses (el ultimo cambio para añadir un campo nuevo...)
Investigaré por si alguien me la esta abriendo como no debe y ha pillado el password...

Muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: No es que no te creyéramos, pero no te creíamos que todo fuera cadena de texto y cadena de fecha :)

Comment: ¿Podría ser alguna actualización de windows?

Comment: Podría ser.... no he encontrado nada. Y mirando logs de los accesos tampoco he encontrado que ningún usuario haya accedido al archivo en modo que no sea usuario. Me tiene bastante mosqueado el tema

Comment: Pues sí que es raro. Para saber por qué ha sucedido y evitar problemas futuros, estaría bien que pusieras cómo declaras la variable 'incorpfecha' y cómo y de dónde actualizas su valor.
Siempre es bueno para evitar problemas de tipos, tipar previamente, con 'CStr' en este caso, así te aseguras que los valores son buenos, especialmente cuando la variable no es string, como el caso de las fechas y demás. Algo así:
'.Subject = "[XX] Nueva Incorporacion " & "Alta de" & " " & NOMBRE & " " & APELLIDOS & "(" & Cstr(INCORPFECHA) & ")"'